# Fix div to right

Tags: html, css

http://tinkerbin.com/OREvWmf6

What im trying to do, is ensure my logo stays on the right side...

So the links would wrap on the left. But instead, they push the logo down.

Top image is desired, bottom is what I get.
[image]

```
<div style="width: 100%; height: 75px; background:#B9C7D4" >
        Link 1
    Link2
    Link 3
          Link 1
    Link2
    Link 3
          Link 1
    Link2
    Link 3
          Link 1
    Link2
    Link 3
     <img height=75px style="float:right;" src="http://dogmatic69.com/files/portfolio/image/4f288818-c5a8-4872-a003-06376318cd71/stackoverflow-logo.png" alt=""/>

</div>
```

Comment: Move the img to before the links.  Just slide it up as the first child of your parent div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your image first:

```
<div style="width: 100%; height: 75px; background:#B9C7D4" >
     <img height=75px style="float:right;" src="http://dogmatic69.com/files/portfolio/image/4f288818-c5a8-4872-a003-06376318cd71/stackoverflow-logo.png" alt=""/>

        Link 1
    Link2
    Link 3
          Link 1
    Link2
    Link 3
          Link 1
    Link2
    Link 3
          Link 1
    Link2
    Link 3

</div>
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, can you explain the reasoning for why it works this way?

Answer (score 1):

It'd be easiest if you structured it in this way:

```
<div class="wrapper clearfix">
    <div class="links"><!-- ul with links or whatever --></div>
    <div class="logo"><img /></div>
</div>
```

With styles:

```
<style type="text/css">
.links { width: 250px; float: left;}
.logo  { width: 75px; float: right; }
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
    content:"";
    display:table;
 }
 .clearfix:after {
    clear:both;
 }
 /* For IE 6/7 (trigger hasLayout) */
 .clearfix {
    zoom:1;
 }
 </style>
```

Note: clearfix code stolen from [What methods of ‘clearfix’ can I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211383/which-method-of-clearfix-is-best)

Answer (score 0):

```
<img height=75px style="float:right;position:absolute;top:0px;right:0px;" src="http://dogmatic69.com/files/portfolio/image/4f288818-c5a8-4872-a003-06376318cd71/stackoverflow-logo.png" alt=""/>
```